# How to order the headers for DictWriter (not alphabetical)?

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I am trying to export a html table to a CSV file. It currently works, but the headers are all jumbled up. I read somewhere that that's what DictWriter does, but I need a way to correct this.

If I were specify `headers = ["Apples", "Bananas", "Oranges"]` and followed this up with, `w = csv.DictWriter(response, fieldnames=headers())` and `w.writeheader()`, I would get headers in the exact order I specified, but I can't do this because I am using it for multiple files that need different headers.

Here is my code:

```
# CSV function
def intents_to_csv(data, file_name, *args, **kwargs):

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=".{}.csv"'.format(file_name)
    w1 = csv.writer(response, delimiter=',')

    headers = [x for x in data[0]]
    w = csv.DictWriter(response, fieldnames=headers) # writing the csv data to a response object.
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerows(data)
    return response
```

Example of data gathering for the function:

```
student_intents = []
for intent in fall_info:
        data = {}
        data["Employee"] = intent.employee
        data["Position"] = intent.position
        data["Cross Train"] = intent.cross_train
        data["Shirtsize"] = intent.shirtsize()
        data["Email"] = intent.employee.email
        data["Phone #"] = intent.employee.phone
        data["Date Created"] = intent.date_created.date()
        student_intents.append(data)
return intents_to_csv(student_intents, file_name)
```

When I run `print(headers)` they print in this order:

```
['Email', 'Position', 'Employee', 'Cross Train', 'Shirtsize', 'Phone #', 'Date Created']
```

EDIT: Seems like just "Email" and "Employee" are flipped here, but it's even more jumbled for different information with more headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the `DictWriter` class that's affecting the order, it's the fact that `headers` is coming from iterating over a `dict`: `headers = [x for x in data[0]]`. When you iterate over a `dict` in a version of Python prior to 3.7, you get the keys in an arbitrary order.

Your options are to switch to 3.7, to sort the `headers` list into its desired order, if that's something that can be determined, or to use an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) in your data gathering function to maintain the order the keys were added. Or adjust your `intents_to_csv` function to take a predetermined `headers` list and build that in your data gathering functions.

On 3.7, the language requires that iteration match insertion order, so you can just use regular `dict` instances in that version. The standard 3.6 C implementation also maintains insertion order, but that is an implementation detail and should not be relied on.

Comment: I used OrderedDict to preserve the order of the keys, as that seemed like the simplest solution to me. It works now, thank you so much!

Comment: FYI, In Python 3.7 dicts now maintain original insertion order.  Python 3.6 did as well, but was considered an implementation detail.  It was formalized in 3.7.

Comment: @MarkTolonen - thanks, updated. There goes a longstanding sacred cow!

Comment: All of our projects are python 2 :(

Comment: `OrderedDict` should work fine for Python 2 - I agree that they're the simplest solution if the desired order isn't logically derivable from anything in particular.